# Singularity in my system of differential equations causing problems for NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

I have the following differentials equations, with the corresponding initial conditions:

```
lamd[t_] := 
  {lamd1[t], lamd2[t], lamd3[t], lamd4[t], lamd5[t], 
   lamd6[t], lamd7[t], lamd8[t], lamd9[t], lamd10[t]};
u = 2/3
r1[t_] = (u *rho1[t]/3) {-2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
r2[t_] = (u*rho2[t]/3) {1, 1, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
r3[t_] = (u*rho3[t]/3) {-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2};
r4[t_] = (u*rho4[t]/3) {2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2};
r = {r1[t], r2[t], r3[t], r4[t]};    
rho[t_] := {rho1[t], rho2[t], rho3[t], rho4[t]};
Gij = 1 - IdentityMatrix[10];

eqn = 
  {rho'[t] == - 2 rho[t]*(Total[Gij.lamd'[t]]/9) + r.(Gij.lamd'[t]), 
   lamd''[t] == 
     -lamd'[t] (Total[Gij.lamd'[t]]/9) + lamd'[t].(Gij.lamd'[t])/9 + 
     (kappa^2)*(res-2*Total[rho[t]]/9), 
   rho[Exp[12]] == rhoinit, lamd[Exp[12]] == lambinit, 
   lamd'[Exp[12]] == lambdinit};
```

The differential equation for `lamd''[t]` being

```
lamd''[t] == 
  -lamd'[t] (Total[Gij.lamd'[t]]/9) + lamd'[t].(Gij.lamd'[t])/9 + 
  (kappa^2)*(res-2*Total[rho[t]]/9)
```

where the terms

```
lamd'[t].(Gij.lamd'[t])/9
```

and

```
kappa^2*(2*Total[rho[t]]/9)
```

are supposed to be same and because of the relative negative sign should cancel each other numerically. When I remove the two terms, I get the correct answers, but when I add the two terms into the differential equation, I get a stiffness error.

Now now I change the coefficients of both the terms (the above same stated terms) starting from zero to 0.4 it seems to work well, but 0.45 seems to lead to singularity. Apparently, `lamd'[t]` seems to blow up just before the singularity and I don't understand why should this happen. And the reason I want to debug this error even when I know the two terms should cancel out is that this code will lead me to another set of PDEs where the structure would be similar but I will have to keep the two terms. I have attached the notebook which includes the code to initialize the variables.

Code for initialisation of lamd[t] and rho[t] which gives lamdinit and rhoinit:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
u = 2/3;
g1 = 2 u^2 (1 - IdentityMatrix[4])
g = 1/(2 u^2) (1/3 - IdentityMatrix[4]);
l[t_] := {l1[t], l2[t], l3[t], l4[t]};
f[t_] := g1.Exp[l[t]]
a = {1.61, 2.65, 0.69, 2.1};
b = {-15, -12, -10, -16};
K = (a/Sqrt[g.a.a])*Sqrt[2 + 2. Total[Exp[b]]];

uji1 = {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} u;
uji2 = {1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} u;
uji3 = {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1} u;
uji4 = {1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1} u;
uji = {uji1, uji2, uji3, uji4};

u1 = (u/3) {-2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
u2 = (u/3) {1, 1, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
u3 = (u/3) {-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2};
u4 = (u/3) {2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2};
ut = Transpose[{u1, u2, u3, u4}];

parame = 1/(6 u);
uij1 = parame {2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1};
uij2 = parame {-1, -1, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1};
uij3 = parame {1, -2, 1, -2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
uij4 = parame {-2, 1, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
uij = Transpose[{uij1, uij2, uij3, uij4}];

L1 = -0.2;
L2 = 0.68;
L6 = 0.14;
L7 = -0.3;
L8 = -0.08;
L9 = -0.19;

Li = {L1, L2, L2, L1, -L6 - L7, L6, L7, L8, 
L9, -3 (L1 + L2) - L8 - L9};
w = Li.Li - (Total[Li])^2;
L = Li Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[w];



h[t_] := ut.Exp[uji.lamb[t] + b - 2 Total[lamb[t]]] - 
Total[lamb'[t]] lamb'[t]

r = uij.K + L  (*Initial condition for derivative for \[Lambda]*)
la = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  (*Initial condition for \[Lambda]*)

lamb[t_] := {lamb1[t], lamb2[t], lamb3[t], lamb4[t], lamb5[t], lamb6[t], 
lamb7[t], lamb8[t], lamb9[t], lamb10[t]}

usol = NDSolve[{lamb''[t] == h[t], lamb[Exp[-10]] == la, 
lamb'[Exp[-10]] == r}, {lamb1, lamb2, lamb3, lamb4, lamb5, lamb6, 
lamb7, lamb8, lamb9, lamb10}, {t, -100, 3^50}]
{lamba1, lamba2, lamba3, lamba4, lamba5, lamba6, lamba7, lamba8, 
lamba9, lamba10} =
Evaluate[{lamb1, lamb2, lamb3, lamb4, lamb5, lamb6, lamb7, lamb8, 
lamb9, lamb10} /. Flatten[usol]];

lambinit = 
Evaluate[{lamba1[t], lamba2[t], lamba3[t], lamba4[t], lamba5[t], 
lamba6[t], lamba7[t], lamba8[t], lamba9[t], 
lamba10[t]} /. {t -> Exp[4]}]

rhoinit = Exp[uji.lambinit + b - 2 Total[lambinit]]
lambdinit = 
Evaluate[{lamba1'[t], lamba2'[t], lamba3'[t], lamba4'[t], lamba5'[t],
 lamba6'[t], lamba7'[t], lamba8'[t], lamba9'[t], 
lamba10'[t]} /. {t -> Exp[4]}]
Plot[Evaluate[{lamba1[t], lamba2[t], lamba3[t], lamba4[t], lamba5[t], 
lamba6[t], lamba7[t]} /. {t -> Exp[t]}], {t, -10, 50}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
Plot[Evaluate[{lamba8[t], lamba9[t], 
lamba10[t]} /. {t -> Exp[t]}], {t, -10, 50}]
```

The main part of the code containing the ODE:

```
Clear[m, w, r, rho]

Gij = 1 - IdentityMatrix[10];
gij = 1/9 - IdentityMatrix[10];

m[t_] := {m1[t], m2[t], m3[t], m4[t], m5[t], m6[t], m7[t], m8[t], 
m9[t], m10[t]};
w[t_] :=  m[t];
gw[t_] := Total[D[w[t], {m[t]}]];

r1[t_] = (u *rho1[t]/3) {-2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
r2[t_] = (u*rho2[t]/3) {1, 1, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
r3[t_] = (u*rho3[t]/3) {-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2};
r4[t_] = (u*rho4[t]/3) {2, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2};
r = {r1[t], r2[t], r3[t], r4[t]};
rho[t_] := {rho1[t], rho2[t], rho3[t], rho4[t]};
res = Total[r];
lamd[t_] := {lamd1[t], lamd2[t], lamd3[t], lamd4[t], lamd5[t], 
lamd6[t], lamd7[t], lamd8[t], lamd9[t], lamd10[t]};
kappa = 1;
k = 1;




eqn = {rho'[t] == - 2 rho[t]*(Total[Gij.lamd'[t]]/9) + r.(Gij.lamd'[t]), 
lamd''[t] == -lamd'[t] (Total[Gij.lamd'[t]]/9) + lamd'[t].(Gij.lamd'[t])/
  9 + (kappa^(2))*(-2*Total[rho[t]]/9 + (res)), rho[Exp[4]] == rhoinit, 
lamd[Exp[4]] == lambinit, lamd'[Exp[4]] == lambdinit };

usol1 = NDSolve[eqn, {lamd1, lamd2, lamd3, lamd4, lamd5, lamd6, lamd7, 
lamd8,lamd9, lamd10, rho1, rho2, rho3, rho4}, {t, Exp[-10], Exp[40]}];
{lamba1, lamba2, lamba3, lamba4, lamba5, lamba6, lamba7, lamda8, 
lamda9, lamda10, rhoa1, rhoa2, rhoa3, rhoa4} =
Evaluate[{lamd1, lamd2, lamd3, lamd4, lamd5, lamd6, lamd7, lamd8, 
 lamd9, lamd10, rho1, rho2, rho3, rho4} /. Flatten[usol1]];
```

The two parts of the code, i.e., the initialization part and the main part, are the same, so the output graphs are expected to be same.

Comment: Hello, welcome to mathematica.SE. Then, please avoid using external link to provide the code sample, because the link can be easily broken.

Comment: @xzczd is there any way I can attach the mathematica notebook rather than providing the external link.

Comment: You don't need to attach the notebook, just copy and paste the code here. (If the code is too long to post, it should be simplified properly. )

Comment: Your question is incomplete. We need to know what `rhoinit` and `lambinit` are, and we need to your `NDSolve` expression.

Comment: I have added the full code which contains two parts. First part containing the initialisation of rhoinit and lambinit. Second part contains the NDSolve.